# Issue regarding provisioning profile ios

Tags: ios

As I am new to iOS, I don't know much about it. So please help me
First someone tell me , what is the purpose of provisioning profile.
Second, is it possible to create a provisioning profile without having an Apple Developer Membership??
Help would be appreciated..

Comment: Without provisioning profile you can't send build to iPhone devices except your device which you can connect thru iPhone cable. \n You can't create provisional certificate without paid developer membership.

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning profile is **impossible** to obtain without Apple Developer Membership.

Nevertheless Provisioning profile is required to test application on real devices and use it to upload application it to App store.

Provision profile is  :

> A provisioning profile is a collection of digital entities that
>   uniquely ties developers and devices to an authorized iPhone
>   Development Team and enables a device to be used for testing. A
>   Development Provisioning Profile must be installed on each device on
>   which you wish to run your application code. Each Development
>   Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development
>   Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an App ID. Devices
>   specified within the provisioning profile can be used for testing only
>   by those individuals whose iPhone Development Certificates are
>   included in the profile. A single device can contain multiple
>   provisioning profiles.

Comment: If it helps you pleas check answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this link please , the author explains everything regardless the provisioning profile .

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-part-1/

However you can not get a provisional profile without the  Apple Developer Membership.

Also if you want to test you app on a real device or publish it to app store you must have a provisional profile.

Answer (score 0):

*"A provisioning profile is a collection of digital entities that uniquely ties developers and devices to an authorized iPhone Development Team and enables a device to be used for testing. A Development Provisioning Profile must be installed on each device on which you wish to run your application code. Each Development Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an App ID. Devices specified within the provisioning profile can be used for testing only by those individuals whose iPhone Development Certificates are included in the profile. A single device can contain multiple provisioning profiles."*

**No, it is not possible to create a provision profile without Apple Developer Membership. If you are deploying an ios App you need to get registered with APPLE.**

You need to register your devices' UDIDs in the provisioning profile if you are testing your app and if you want to use it for Ad-hocs.

If you want to submit your app to appstore, then also you will require a provision profile attached with your app having 0 devices i.e infinite devices.

Here is the way you can register and make Provision Profiles:

[How to create provision profiles?](http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/ave-digital-publishing-from-zave-to-app/developer-apple-com-2/adding-development-and-distribution-provisioning-profiles/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ans 1 : To run or test the application in ios device provisional profile is 
must  require.  
Without it you can not run/test/install in your device.For this you have 
to buy Apple Developer Membership from Apple 
to became apple registered developer. 
After successfully registration below link will useful to create provisional profile.

Link : http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone 

After downloading provisional profile you have to install and set that profile in your   code. 
After you can run application in ios device.

Ans 2 : No, Without Apple Developer Membership you can not create provisional profile.
```